# Who introduced direct limits?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, set-theory, lo.logic, ho.history-overview

The general notion of a direct limit of a commuting system of embeddings, indexed by pairs in a directed set, has seen heavy use in set theory.  It is the same notion as in category theory.  I was surprised to find that the general definition does not appear in the book on model theory by Chang and Keisler ([MR1059055](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1059055)).  Who was the originator of this idea?

Comment: Probably it was done first with groups?  At first just a sequence of groups.

Comment: It's hard to say when it was first done: it might have been done first in significant particular case, etc. Then maybe formalized but not in a very definite way. Also category theory unified the notion with the dual notions since it allows to treat arrows and their opposite in the same point of view. And of course the categorical definition doesn't supersede any specific case: how some kind of limits can be described in a given category of algebraic structures is also part of the job.

Comment: I think an early example outside groups was Dieudonné and Schwartz's [paper on (LF) spaces](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1949__1__61_0.pdf). Each time it occurs, «limite inductive» is put in (French) quotation marks, as if the term is being used slightly outside its strict meaning. Schwartz's earlier papers describe the topology on compactly supported test functions directly in terms of convergence, rather than as the direct limit of a sequence of Fréchet spaces.

Comment: That what categorists would now call **cofiltered limits** were first introduced for groups in the 1930s is entirely plausible.  The unification of this notion with products, equalisers and pullbacks in category theory was made by **Peter Freyd** in his thesis in about 1963.

Comment: @PaulTaylor "Direct limit" is the old-fashioned name for a filtered colimit (indexed by a poset), rather than a cofiltered limit, which were called an "inverse limit", or "projective limit".

Comment: @RobertFurber Yes, I believe you are correct.  I was misled by the reference to groups, where profinite Galois groups are natural and I wonder why one would draw attention to filtered colimits.

Comment: @PaulTaylor I believe Pontryagin concerned himself with filtered colimits because they give a way of calculating the dual group to a cofiltered limit. At least, that is my reading of the bottom of p. 197 of the article suggested by Cameron Zwarich. I can't be certain because both my German and my understanding of the historical terminology of group theory and algebraic topology are not up to scratch.

Answer (score 28):

The definition of a direct limit of groups was given by Pontrjagin in his 1931 paper [Über den algebraischen Inhalt topologischer Dualitätssätze](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01455814)

Answer (score 22):

As suggested by Gerald, the notion was first introduced for groups. Given a directed system of groups, their direct limit was defined as a quotient of their direct product (which was referred to as their "weak product"). The general notion is a clear generalization, although the original reference only deals with groups. As mentioned by Cameron Zwarich in the other [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/357967/6085), the definition can be traced back at least to Lev Pontryagin.

For an early exposition in English, see

> [MR0007093 (4,84f)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=7093). Lefschetz, Solomon. **Algebraic Topology**. American Mathematical Society Colloquium Publications, v. 27. American Mathematical Society, New York, 1942. vi+389 pp.

Specifically, direct limits are defined in Chapter 2, $\S$14 (p. 57).

Comment: According to van Est ([1999](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0948.01038)): “Inverse limits of groups had occurred earlier in mathematics (e.g., Brouwer, [1910](//www.dwc.knaw.nl/toegangen/digital-library-knaw/?pagetype=publDetail&pId=PU00013496); van Dantzig, [1930](//zbmath.org/?q=an:56.1130.01); Herbrand, 1933), and of course examples abound in *p*-adics (...) These matters are discussed in the introduction of (Freudenthal, [1937](//zbmath.org/?q=an:0016.28001)) (...) It is, we think, by this paper that the notions of inverse and direct limit acquired their formal status in mathematics”.

Comment: Unfortunately what he says is not quite unambiguous. Certainly Pontrjagin is among those quoted by Freudenthal 1937, but you’d have to unravel the direct vs inverse aspect.

Comment: @Francois I rephrased. Thanks!